# Range loop printing out the range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, range

When I am trying to loop through the days of the week, the output seems to simply be the start date and end date of the range, rather than the name of the day I am trying to print out.

I am doing it this way as there are more pieces of content I want to print out per day. Here's what I have in my model:

```
(Date.today.beginning_of_week..Date.today.end_of_week).each do |day|
    day.strftime("%A")
end
```

I have no idea why all I am getting in the view is this:

```
2015-10-05..2015-10-11
```

If someone could shed some light on this, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: How do you define a week? Sunday through Saturday? OR Today's day +/- 3 days? Could you also post the code in the view that is displaying this? (not just the model method)

Comment: Monday through to Sunday, in my view I simply have <%= @timetable.weekdays %> as it is in a method labelled weekdays in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting it to return an array, but it's just returning the original Range object:

```
(Date.today.beginning_of_week..Date.today.end_of_week)
```

because it is being called with `:each`. You could use `:map` instead:

```
(Date.today.beginning_of_week..Date.today.end_of_week).map {|date| date}
```

but if you don't need to transform the dates while enumerating them, you can simply use `:to_a`:

```
(Date.today.beginning_of_week..Date.today.end_of_week).to_a
```

Comment: This is the best solution, since it appears that OP wants the array of the results printed. For new Ruby devs, `map` is very useful and will save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are printing the result, but if you have `puts` on the entire code you cited, then it will print the receiver of `each` (range of dates; what you have now). If you want to print what you have inside the block, then put `puts` inside the block.

```
(Date.today.beginning_of_week..Date.today.end_of_week).each do |day|
  puts day.strftime("%A")
end
```